# Search first click doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, reportviewer

I'm using ReportViewer to display data.I didn't want to load data in Page_Load (it takes a lot of time to load the page as i have a lot of data).
I have a probleme when i click in search button, it load all data at first click, after the second click it filters the data.
Any idea how to filter data in first click 
my code looks like that:

- C# :

  ```
  protected void LinkButton_FilterArticles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      try
      {                                           
          ReportViewer_DetailsArticles.LocalReport.Refresh();
          ReportViewer_DetailsArticles.ShowReportBody = true;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```
- asp.net web forms :

  ```
  <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer_DetailsArticles" runat="server">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="BO\Report\Report_DetailsArticles.rdlc">
      <DataSources>
        <rsweb:ReportDataSource Name="DataSet_DetailsArticles" DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource_DetailsArticles"></rsweb:ReportDataSource>
      </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
  </rsweb:ReportViewer>
  <asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="ObjectDataSource_DetailsArticles" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="MICIEN.BO.DataSet.DataSet_DetailsArticlesTableAdapters.Reporting_SearchFromDetailsArticlesTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="GetData">
     <SelectParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox_DateDecisionFrom" PropertyName="Text" Name="DateDecisionFrom" Type="DateTime"></asp:ControlParameter>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox_DateDecisionTo" PropertyName="Text" Name="DateDecisionTo" Type="DateTime"></asp:ControlParameter>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox_DateReceptionFrom" PropertyName="Text" Name="DateReceptionDemandeFrom" Type="DateTime"></asp:ControlParameter>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox_DateReceptionTo" PropertyName="Text" Name="DateReceptionDemandeTo" Type="DateTime"></asp:ControlParameter>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox_CodeSH" PropertyName="Text" Name="ArticleCodeExt" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox_Importateur" PropertyName="Text" Name="Importer" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList_Laboratoire" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="Laboratoire" Type="Int32"></asp:ControlParameter>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList_Bureau" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="Bureau" Type="Int32"></asp:ControlParameter>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList_FamilleProduit" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="FamilleProduit" Type="Int32"></asp:ControlParameter> </SelectParameters> </asp:ObjectDataSource>
  ```

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added to my stored procedure a parameter '@Show bit' and in where statement I set ' @Show = 1', then I added a hiddenfield to the page aspx like this:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField_Show" runat="server" />
```

Data source parameter:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenField_Show" PropertyName="Value" Name="Show" Type="Boolean" DefaultValue="False"></asp:ControlParameter>
```

My new C# code looks like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                HiddenField_Show.Value = "False";
                ReportViewer_DetailsArticles.LocalReport.Refresh();
                ReportViewer_DetailsArticles.ShowReportBody = true;
            }
            else HiddenField_Show.Value = "True";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    protected void LinkButton_FilterArticles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            HiddenField_Show.Value = "True";
            ReportViewer_DetailsArticles.LocalReport.Refresh();
            ReportViewer_DetailsArticles.ShowReportBody = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have date parameter then this link might be help you:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9eaf22de-54d7-4b71-8a61-0b28b4c28b55/report-viewer-showing-empty-page-when-i-first-click-on-view-report-in-ssrs-but-shows-for-next-click?forum=sqlreportingservices